# How to use Fluid api in Entity .net Core 2.1 to set field to 'date'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a Model class that defines various fields. I can set the field to be 'datetime' and Entity Framework builds the table and uses 'datetime2(7).

I am trying to override that to set the mssql field to 'date'.  I really don't want the time portion.

Likewise, I have another field that I want to set to 'time' (of day).  I cannot set that either.

(And for optional completeness, I would like a field for time duration, but I will have to burn that bridge when I come to it.)

This question more broadly applies to using Fluid api to generate any other specific fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `date` type column you would use `DateTime` type property and [`HasColumnType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertybuilderextensions.hascolumntype?view=efcore-2.0) Fluent API:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    // ...
    public DateTime DateVal { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .Property(e => e.DateVal)
    .HasColumnType("date");
```

For `time` type column you would simply use `TimeSpan` type property (no Fluent API is needed):

```
public class MyEntity
{
    // ...
    public TimeSpan TimeVal { get; set; }
}
```

The generated SQL command from the migration would be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyEntity] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [DateVal] date NOT NULL,
    [TimeVal] time NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyEntity] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);
```

Comment: I don't know why my attempt at the 'date' failed continuously.  But after reading yours, mine now works. The reference to "TimeSpan' passes the migration but fails the update-database with 'Cannot find datatype timespan.'.  Reading more about 'timespan' or 'duration' indicates these are represented as Time Of Day types, so I switched to 'int' for my duration field, as an hour is close enough accuracy.

Comment: So to be complete, your 'date' suggestion worked perfect, don't know why mine kept failing.  The 'timespan' fails at the update-database step.  And I chickened out with duration.